# Writing del, divergence, and curl in generalized coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, derivatives, notation, vector-fields

In three dimensional Cartesian coordinates the Hamilton operator, del, is written as

$\nabla=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix}$

The divergence of a vector field $A$ is written as

$\nabla \cdot A=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix} 
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_x \\
A_y \\
A_z
\end{pmatrix} =\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z}
$

The curl is writtten as

$\nabla \times A=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}
\end{pmatrix} 
\times 
\begin{pmatrix}
A_x \\
A_y \\
A_z
\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial y} -\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial z} -\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial x} \\
\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} -\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y}
\end{pmatrix} 
$

I am trying to write these three equations for generalized coordinates using the Einstein summation convention and the basis vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, and $e_3$ for the scalars $x^1$, $x^2$, and $x^3$

So far I have the equations for gradient and divergence as

$\nabla= e_\mu \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$

$\nabla \cdot A= e_\mu \cdot\frac{\partial A_\mu}{\partial x^\mu}$

Are these equations correct? What would the equation for curl be?

Comment: @DomDoe that is the Hamiltonian operator

Comment: No, they're not correct at all (and the second one doesn't make sense to begin with). There's [a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates) describing the formulas for typical specific cases and [one with the general case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvilinear_coordinates). Why don't you start there, and come back here if you have specific questions?

Comment: The specific pages for grad (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient), div (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergence), curl (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curl_(mathematics)) also have generalized versions. You will need some grasp of what vectors and co-vectors are, what is metric, what is covariant derivative, what is the connection, Levi-Civita relative tensors, and generalized Kroenecker deltas. This is for completely arbitrary coordinates. Simpler expressions are available if you stick with curvilinear coordinates

Comment: @Cryo *"You will need some grasp of [long list of things that are arcane and mysterious right up until they are easy and obvious]"* OK. That made me chuckle.

Answer (score 1):

$\nabla_aA_b = \partial_aA_b-\Gamma^c_{\space \space ab}A_c$

$\nabla_aA^b = \partial_aA^b+\Gamma^b_{\space \space ac}A^c$

$(\nabla f)^a = g^{ab}\partial_b$f

$\nabla^2f=\nabla_a\nabla^af=g^{ab}(\partial_a\partial_b-\Gamma^c_{\space \space ab}\partial_c)f$

$\nabla \cdot F = \nabla_aF^a= \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_a(\sqrt{g}F^a)$

$(\nabla \times F)^\mu =?\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}} \epsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_{\nu}F_{\lambda}$